# using this in EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am upgrading my project from MVC3 LinqtoSql to MVC5 Entities Framework 6.02.

I instantiate class with partial class.  Using Database First I made my Entities model, that has a class called `Exercise`, added a folder called partial and made a new model called Exercise.  Exactly as the old project.
In my old project partial class I used the following:

```
public string PhysicalActivity
{
    get { return MapPhysicalActivityValue(this.PhysicalActivityID); }
    set { this.PhysicalActivityID = MapPhysicalActivityValue(value); }
}
```

I tried to do the same for the new project but having a problem using "this"; I had to change it to:

```
public string PhysicalActivity
{
    get { return MapPhysicalActivityValue(Models.Exercise.PhysicalActivityID); }
    set { Models.Exercise.PhysicalActivityID = MapPhysicalActivityValue(value); }
}
```

Any idea why I can't use "this"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to use `this`?

Comment: If I use this.PhysicalActivityID, can't resolve PhysicalActivityID.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like `PhysicalActivityID` is `static`. Did EF generate it or did you add it manually in your partial file?

Comment: It is virtual, generated by EF.  EF classes are partial too, could be this the reason it is can't be resolved.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the namespace
The Entity Model namespace Models, and I used namespace Models.Partial (for the directory), I removed Partial and all works great.  Hope this could help someone having the same problem.